# Python dash call back function

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

This maybe asking alot, but I was curious if anyone had any tips for combining these two dash scripts. The purpose would be to incorporate the drop down menu to remove/add data points on the visualization plots.

The first script will visualize my data nicely and the second script with the callback function is for creating a drop down menu from the [plotly tutorials](https://dash.plot.ly/dash-core-components/dropdown).

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go


external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)



df = pd.read_csv('boilerData.csv', index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)
df = df.fillna(method = 'ffill').fillna(method = 'bfill')




app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(
        id='hws',
        figure={
            'data': [
                {'x': df.index, 'y': df.HWST, 'type': 'line', 'name': 'hwst'},
                {'x': df.index, 'y': df.HWRT, 'type': 'line', 'name': 'hwrt'},
                {'x': df.index, 'y': df.OAT, 'type': 'line', 'name': 'oat'},
            ],
            'layout': {
                'title': 'Heating System Data Visualization'
            }
        }
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

dropdown script:

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='my-dropdown',
        options=[
            {'label': 'Outdoor Temp', 'value': 'OAT'},
            {'label': 'Hot Water Supply Temp', 'value': 'HWST'},
            {'label': 'Hot Water Return Temp', 'value': 'HWRT'}
        ],
        value=['OAT','HWST','HWRT'],
        multi=True
    ),
    html.Div(id='output-container')
])


@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('output-container', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('my-dropdown', 'value')])
def update_output(value):
    return 'You have selected "{}"'.format(value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Any tips help, still learning...

Comment: How exactly do you want your dropdown to work? What data do you want it to hide/show based on what choices? Can you share some data or use something that we can test on?

Comment: I was hoping in the drop down the person could select between the points `HWST, HWRT, OAT` whether they want to see all 3 on a plot or just one/two..

Comment: I have the data in this github repo, thank you for any help you can give me. https://github.com/bbartling/Heating-Plant-Analysis

Comment: boilerData.csv file

Comment: I updated it with your data. Does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to know is that the callback takes `Input` from some Dash element (here the `value` of the dropdown) and returns to `Output` for some property of another Dash element (here the `figure` from the graph; notice we only change the `data` property).

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)



df = pd.read_csv('boilerData.csv', index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)
df = df.fillna(method = 'ffill').fillna(method = 'bfill')

app.layout = html.Div([

    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='my-dropdown',
        options=[
            {'label': 'Outdoor Temp', 'value': 'OAT'},
            {'label': 'Hot Water Supply Temp', 'value': 'HWST'},
            {'label': 'Hot Water Return Temp', 'value': 'HWRT'}
        ],
        value=['OAT','HWST','HWRT'],
        multi=True
    ),

    dcc.Graph(
        id='hws',
        figure={
            'data': [
                {'x': df.index, 'y': df.HWST, 'type': 'line', 'name': 'hwst'},
                {'x': df.index, 'y': df.HWRT, 'type': 'line', 'name': 'hwrt'},
                {'x': df.index, 'y': df.OAT, 'type': 'line', 'name': 'oat'},
            ],
            'layout': {
                'title': 'Heating System Data Visualization'
            }
        }
    )
])


@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('hws', 'figure'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('my-dropdown', 'value')])
def update_output(columns):
    return {"data": [{'x': df.index, 'y': df[col], 'type':'line', 'name': col}
                     for col in columns]}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Cool thanks for the response, I'm AFK but will be back soon.

Comment: It appears to be working.. If I select or deselect different points (`HWST, HWRT, OAT`) to be visible I have to hit the small icon in the bottom right hand corner `Callback graph` and it will update..  :) Thank you

Comment: One other question I have is it possible with dash to bring a calculated parameter up to the front end? I think I could this with Flask & Jinja... For example in dash maybe between an HTML div, would it be possible to show something like correlation between two points? IE, `correlation = df['HWST'].corr(df['OAT'])`

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean "correlation between two points" (you mean arrays?) and "bring [...] to the front end" but if you want to have details about specific points appear on hover, there is a parameter (I think `description`) for that in plotly/dash graphs. If you want something to appear in another element (say the correlation you calculated with a few comments) you can create another `html.P` element (or other) in your `app.layout` and then modify the callback to have 2 outputs: `[Output('hws', 'figure'), Output('myP', 'children')], [Input(...)]`